# Change the Toast display position

Tags: android

I want to change Toast display postion, and i use setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0); But i found it doesn't work. It displays like the default(at the bottom of screen). Where is the proplem? Thanks.

Here is my java code

```
public class ToastViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mBtnToast1,mBtnToast2,mBtnToast3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_toast_view);
        setTitle("Learn ToastView");
        mBtnToast1 = findViewById(R.id.btn_toast_1);
        mBtnToast2 = findViewById(R.id.btn_toast_2);
        mBtnToast3 = findViewById(R.id.btn_toast_3);
        OnClick onClick = new OnClick();
        mBtnToast1.setOnClickListener(onClick);
        mBtnToast2.setOnClickListener(onClick);
        mBtnToast3.setOnClickListener(onClick);
    }

    class OnClick implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.btn_toast_1 :
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Toast",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_toast_2 :
                    Toast toastCenter = Toast.makeText(ToastViewActivity.this,"CENTER",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toastCenter.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                    toastCenter.show();
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_toast_3 :
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You sure you are clicking the right button?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#setGravity(int,%20int,%20int) "Starting from Android Build.VERSION_CODES#R, for apps targeting API level Build.VERSION_CODES#R or higher, this method is a no-op when called on text toasts."

Comment: as @CommonsWare said, Toast position changes are no longer supported since Android API 30. Maybe you should consider different design choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately setting `Toast` gravity is no longer supported. If you take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#setGravity(int,%20int,%20int)) it specifically says:

> Warning: Starting from Android Build.VERSION_CODES#R, for apps targeting API level Build.VERSION_CODES#R or higher, this method is a no-op when called on text toasts.

---

To get the required behaviour you would have to implement a custom solution.